# Summarizing Term for "Structured Data" and "Unstructured Data"

Tags: hypernyms

I am currently writing a survey paper in the computer science domain. At one point, I distinguish between "structured data" and "unstructured data". I need a summarizing term for both (to name the dimension, "data" would be too broad). Is there a better term than "structuredness" (in case that even exists...)?

Comment: Even in the database domain I can't think of a correct term for what you need. But you must know that *Structured* means the data has a pattern, such as each record always beginning with the last name then the first. It is this kind of data that you can form into a database that is normalized to some extent.  Awaiting your comments.

Comment: See [*What is the opposite of **raw data**?*](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-opposite-of/raw_data.html). Also [*synonyms/antonyms of raw data*](https://www.synonym.com/synonyms/raw-data) - probably a software-generated page, but it definitely reflects the well-known distinction between ***data*** and ***information***, which is probably relevant to your context.

Comment: One word requests require an example sentence. “Structuredness does not exist — the noun is “structure”, but I don’t see how this would cover the two types of data.

Comment: What makes this about English, not some computer science, information technology or data processing language?

You introduced the terms so how, in your view, could "structured…" and "unstructured data" not be summarized as "data", even if that was a "dimension"?

Your problem repeats itself in the query "Is there a better term than 'structuredness…" which clearly exists until you cite some technical dictionaries or glossaries relevant to your work which say otherwise.

"… structuredness…" begs the Question "… structuredness…" of what? Of data?

Can you find a CS, IT or DP forum?